# Subsetting by NA when merge output creates both "<NA>" and NA in R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, na

I'm importing two .csv files to R. Neither contain any empty or NULL values, nor any "NA" strings.

```
df1 <- read.csv("df1.csv")
df2 <- read.csv("df2.csv")
```

They both look a bit like this, same exact column names:

```
> head(df1)

Chrom Position Gene.Sym Target.ID Type Zygosity Genotype Ref
1 chr10 99219404 MMS19 MMS19_104345.9376 DEL Het TG/T TG
2 chr2 109411248 CCDC138 CCDC138_27210.755 DEL Het GAATAT/G GAATAT
3 chr22 50687970 HDAC10 HDAC10_192036.1834 DEL Het CAT/C CAT
```

I merge df1 and df2 on the basis of three column names:

```
merged <- merge(df1, df2, by = c("Chrom", "Position", "Gene.Sym"), all = T)
```

Here's a portion of dataframe "merged"; **it has replaced numeric values with NA and other strings with "< NA >":**

```
>head(mergedJec12)
  Chrom Position Gene.Sym     Target.ID.x Type.x Zygosity.x Genotype.x Ref.x Variant.x Var.Freq.x
1  chr1   861368   SAMD11            <NA>   <NA>       <NA>       <NA>  <NA>      <NA>         NA
2  chr1   871334   SAMD11 SAMD11_11.11186    SNP        Het        G/T     G         T   53.06122
3  chr1   876499   SAMD11  SAMD11_14.6196    SNP        Hom        G/G     A         G  100.00000
```

I want to subset by certain columns that contain NA, but the inconsistency created by its variable incarnations in "merged" creates a problem. Okay, so I do this:

```
merged[merged == '' | merged == 'NA' | merged == '<NA>'] <- NA
```

but it doesn't change "merged" whatsoever. The "< NA >"s and NAs remain the same. What am I missing here?

Also, when I run

```
NA.only <- merged[regexpr('<NA>', merged$Target.ID.x)>0,]
```

to try and make a dataframe containing only those rows that contain the value  in column merged$Target.ID.x, I instead get a dataframe completely full of NAs and "< NA >"s. I'm mystified.

Just as a note, I'm writing out "< NA >" with spaces to avoid markup deletion. There are no spaces in the literals.

Comment: you should be using `is.na()` rather than `== NA`

Comment: It's probably a problem created by trying to merge factors with different levels. Do a `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in your initial `read.csv` calls and see if goes away after the merge.

Comment: @Thomas: same result as before

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have `all=TRUE`. The `<NA>` values are for observations that exist in one dataframe but not the other. See [the documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html) regarding the `all.x` and `all.y` arguments:

> **all.x**:    logical; if TRUE, then extra rows will be added to the output, one for each row in x that has no matching row in y. These rows will have NAs in those columns that are usually filled with values from y. The default is FALSE, so that only rows with data from both x and y are included in the output.

The reason why some missing values are shown as `NA` versus `<NA>` has to do, as in my comment, with factors versus other classes. `<NA>` is displayed for factors:

```
> c(1,2,3,NA)
[1]  1  2  3 NA
> factor(c(1,2,3,NA))
[1] 1    2    3    <NA>
Levels: 1 2 3
```

Comment: I want the rows with the NAs. My problem is that two different kinds are being produced, seemingly conditional on whether other values in the column are numerical or not.